# Como saber se o Memcached esta conectado com o C#?

Tags: c#, memcached

Como saber se o Memcached esta conectado com o C# ?

Comment: Já tentou utilizá-lo guardando algo em cache e obtendo-o? Dá uma lida nesse [tutorial](http://latebound.blogspot.com.br/2008/10/using-memcached-from-c.html)

Comment: Vou dar uma olha aqui ... Brigado !